# Adding number to all elements of the matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

There was a formula showing how determinant changed if we added some number to all elements of the matrix. There was something like this number multiplied by sum of adjoints?

I searched this website, but couldnt find this formula

Comment: Take a look at the [matrix determinant lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma). In your case, you have to use $u=(1 \;1 \; \ldots \; 1)^T$ and $v=(c\; c\; \ldots \;c)^T$, where $c$ is the number you want to add to each element of the matrix $A$.

Comment: @ReinhardMeier Thanks, that is exactly what I was looking for!